# Nesting Variable inside If Statement

Tags: java, nested

I'm very new to the whole programming world. In fact, I'm taking my very first programming class right now. We're learning Java. Please bear with me as I try to explain what it is I'm looking to do.

In our most recent assignment we were asked to program a game of Craps. The specifications are listed below:

Shooter rolls two dice to get the first sum.
If the first sum is 2, 3, or 12, shooter looses
Otherwise, if rate first sum is 7 or 11, shooter wins.
Otherwise, the first sum becomes the point.

Now keep rolling again and again.
Shooter rolls two dice to get the new sum.
If the new sum equals the point, shooter wins.
Otherwise if the new sum equals 7, shooter loses.
Otherwise shooter rolls again.

Our lesson for this assignment was using if/else statements, do/while statements, and programming a randomizer.

I had it programmed as such:

```
    //Declare
    Random randomizer;

    //Instantiate
    randomizer = new Random();

    //Generate dice number
    int number = randomizer.nextInt(10) + 2;

    //Loop
    if ((number) == 2 || (number) == 3 || (number) == 12) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you rolled a " + number + ". You lose.");
        number = randomizer.nextInt(10) + 2;
    } else {
    if ((number) == 7 || (number) == 11) {
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You rolled a " + number + ". You win!");
    } else {
    if ((number) != 2 || (number) != 3 || (number) != 7 || (number) != 11 || (number) != 12) {
        System.out.println("The number you rolled is a " + number + ". This is your point.")}
    }//Ending bracket of loop
}//Ending bracket of method main
```

According to the instructions, the program needs to hold onto the value of the point for reference later on. The way that I want that to happen is to program after the very last "if" portion for that output (whether it's 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, or 10) to become a variable so that I am able to reference in the second if/then loop for the second portion of the program. So, basically I'll need the program to recognize if the output from the second portion is equal to the variable that was output by the first portion that the shooter wins.

I also need to know how to program it so that the shooter keeps rolling if neither of those conditions is met.

I know that's a lot to ask for and I hoped I was able to explain it well. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Not really related, but you need to roll 2 dices going from 1 to 6 and sum the values, not 1 dice rolling from 2 to 12. The probabilities of the results are not the same. Other than that, you should first try doing it by yourself. As you already know, you need a loop.

Comment: `if ((number) != 2 || (number) != 3 || ...` This will always be true. You want &&, not ||. Better yet, use a switch instead of if-else if-else.

Comment: @JBNizet I've tried doing this by myself, and have been for nearly a week now without any luck, which is why I reached out to the StackOverflow community. I've altered the code so that two dice are rolled rather than one, so thank you for that recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first things first. One of the things about your code that stands out to me is this:

```
((number) == 2 || (number) == 3 || (number) == 12)
```

While not an error, the way you are parenthesizing your arguments is totally unnecessary. You're grouping the variable `number` by itself, which doesn't do anything. You're essentially saying, "group `number` with itself". Instead, try this:

```
((number == 2) || (number == 3) || (number == 12))
```

While the parenthesis here aren't strictly necessary either (order of operations will make sure it works correctly), it's still good form. And in the case above you're saying: "compare `number` to these numbers before evaluating the or", which is what you want.

Next, as @JB Nizet said above, you want to roll two six-sided dies and then add them together. The odds are different.

For what you asked about, what you need to do is save the last result and compare it with the next roll, correct? So what you want to do is save the value of first roll, evaluate it, then save it. Simple. Here's some pseudo-code that should help:

```
finalSum = -1;
while( we are not done) {
    roll1
    roll2
    tempSum = roll1 + roll2

    do all the ifs
    check to see if finalSum is -1, modify if's to account for that

    finalSum = tempSum
    determine if we're done looping, make sure loop breaks
}
```

Set the finalSum as the (next to) last statement in your loop, and just check it against the new roll. If it is -1, you know it is your first roll and you can ignore it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for that information! I'm still having some trouble, though. I've written and rewritten this code so many times that I'm more confused now than when I started. I've altered the code to roll two dice rather than one. However, I now feel that I need to set a bunch of variables and just use those throughout the code. I'm honestly not sure how to go about doing any of this, as it occurred to me last night that I was never taught the foundational requirements for programming.

Comment: Well, we really can't teach you the fundamentals of programming here, but the Internet itself is full of good resources. Sun has a whole series on Java programming from the ground up.